# Wrap figure within a float

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, wrap

In the textbook I am writing, there are some floating boxes with text (I used tcolorbox to define them). I need to place a small picture in some of these boxes, with text wrapping around them.

To wrap around figures, I use the package `wrapfig`, but apparently it doesn't allow to wrap within floats. Any solution to suggest?

Comment: tcolorbox is not a float, but it is a tikzpicture.

Comment: But you can make it a float by using the option `float` when defining the tcolorbox, can't you?

Comment: So does remove float fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given no information about what you tried, or what error message you got, so I can only note that `wrapfigure` works fine in floats.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[pth]

  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}
  \end{wrapfigure}
one two three four one two three four one two three four 
one two three four one two three four one two three four 
one two three four one two three four one two three four 
one two three four one two three four one two three four 
one two three four one two three four one two three four 
one two three four one two three four one two three four 
one two three four one two three four one two three four 
one two three four one two three four one two three four 
one two three four one two three four one two three four 
  \caption{zzzz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right, it works. I am embarassed. In this case I think I can delete the question...

Comment: @Massimo no harm done:-)